# Need to save 5 best times for an Android game

Tags: java, android

I need to save **5** *best times* (an integer) for a game. The game is a reaction time game.

I'm assuming that the *easiest* way to do this would be to store it in a *text file* but I really have no idea how to go about doing this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimer);
    myHandler = new Handler();

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);
            MainActivity.this.textTimer.setVisibility(0);
        }
    });

    pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);

    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            timeSwap += timeInMillies;
            myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);
            MainActivity.this.textTimer.setVisibility(0);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

        int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
        textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
};
```

that is the code i have for now. all i want to happen is that when i press the pause button, it will go to the next screen and display the time. and also there will be a button, let's say "*records*". if it is pressed, it will display the 5 *best times*.

Comment: Check out sharedpreferences

Comment: As Damien R. proposed, the EASIEST way to store a few values is by using the SharedPreferences. You can you can store them as 5 separate integer values (so not to make splits and joins and conversions to/from string) or use a single string value with all your scores separated by... a comma (or any other separator you like).

Comment: Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref I'm pretty sure it'll give you everything you need here.

Comment: Ok now the question is changing, I believe your question is answered. If you have further questions before asking a *new* question please make sure you read a couple stuff and search if it was already asked. After the last edit i realized you already asked this question before, 2 days ago. If it is 2 days, i may think there is *lack of understanding* of what exactly is going on. I suggest you try to understand that code **line by line**, search in google, read about `SharedPreferences` in http://developer.android.com . SO users can't write the whole application for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android codes for recording time (leaderboards)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150941/android-codes-for-recording-time-leaderboards)

Comment: @Zefnus no the question has not been answered yet. can you help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a file to save scores, you can use `SharedPreferences` `putInt()` and `getInt()` methods to save `int` values.

The following sample is a possible (very lazy) implementation of it;

```
protected final static String PREFS_NAME = "PREF_GAME_SCORE";

public static int GetBestScore(Context context, int no) 
{
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    return settings.getInt("Score" + String.valueOf(no), 0); // # 0 is the default value if no data is found
}

public static void SetBestScore(Context context, int no, int score)
{
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("Score" + String.valueOf(no), score);
    editor.commit();
}
```

You can use `SetBestScore(conxtext, 1, 666);` to set the best score #number:1 and to get the best score, use; `GetBestScore(context, 1);`

The values saved using `SharedPreferences` will remain until the application is removed from the device or Application Data is cleared *manually* using:

> Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> (choose your app)
>   -> Clear data

Comment: And the values will also be preserved between your app's updates.

Comment: i palced a down vote only for this "The values saved using SharedPreferences will remain untill the application is removed from the device." They will remain only till the user clears the application data in application settings.

Comment: @Zefnus how can i record the 5 best times with the code you've given? can i share you the codes i have so you can modify it? i still don't get it.

Comment: @Yogamurthy Thank you for pointing. I totally forgot about clearing *Application Data*. But the data will be deleted if application is removed as well. Please check my edit.

Comment: @Al-Rayyan Try to copy paste the sample, and within `onCreate()` add `SetBestScore(this, 1, 22);` setting best time #1 which is: 22. Run your application. Close your application. Remove the line you just added (SetBestScore). Again withing `onCreate()` add `int testInt = GetBestScore(this, 1);`. See if you'll get the value 22. And of course share your code *editing* your question if you think it might help for the solution.

Comment: @Zefnus i already edited my post. can you help me? i already stated how the scenario will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of what [Zefnus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201494/need-to-save-5-best-times-for-an-android-game/22201614#22201614) said, here is a method to send a score in and check if it is in the top lowest scores.  If it is, it sets the `TEMP_SPOT` and then updates accordingly.

You could set any number of top scores too. This could easily be modified to got the other way too, IE, check for high scores.

```
public static void CheckAndSetBestScore(Context context, int score) {
    int TOTAL_TOP_SCORES = 5;
    int TEMP_SPOT = -1;

    SharedPreferences settings = context
            .getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    for (int i = 1; i <= TOTAL_TOP_SCORES; ++i) {

        if (TEMP_SPOT == -1) {
            if (score <= settings.getInt("Score" + String.valueOf(i), 1000)) {
                TEMP_SPOT = i;
            }
        }
    }
    if (TEMP_SPOT != -1) {
        for (int i = TOTAL_TOP_SCORES; i >= TEMP_SPOT; --i) {
            if (i != TEMP_SPOT) {
                editor.putInt("Score" + String.valueOf(i), settings.getInt("Score" + String.valueOf(i - 1), 1000));
            } 
            else {
                editor.putInt("Score" + String.valueOf(i), score);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There are three ways to do it
1. Flat FIle
2. Shared Preferences
3. SQL

Personally i would recommend you to go for SQL, since any of the operation that you want to add in the future makes lesser work.If in case of sharedpreferences you need a whole new set of code to handle a new operation.so better go with sqlite.

Whenever a game is ended take the score and insert it to the table. When you want to display the top 5 results. Do a query with Score in Ascending order and limit to 5 rows. Bingo you can get the result,which you wanted.

Hope it helps.

Take a look at this link for how to create and use an SQL database from android.
http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-24%E2%80%93Using-SQLite-Databases

Comment: For storing data, and generating statistics, reports; `SQLite` would be a good way to go, but i don't think using it for only **5** `int` values is really *necessary*. Handle database creation, table, a row. And what *average*, *sorting* especially *top 5* in **5** rows ?